# Confidence Intervals in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am supposed to calculate different confidence intervals and I found out that, in R, I can do that with the predict-command. But I've got a problem understanding what I have to do really. I am supposed to calculate 3 different confidence intervals:
1) for a point on the regression line
2) for a predicted (future) y-value
3) for the entire regression line.
Ok.. what I've done so far:

```
fm <- lm(alcohol~beers)
```

So, to get the confidence interval for the whole regression line, I'd try:`predict(fm,data.frame(beers = newbeers), level = 0.9, interval = "confidence")`

But I do not really know what data.frame does.
Okay I do know that a confidence interval holds the actual value in 90% of all times (here, because 0.9). So does this now mean it holds best regression line in 90%?
I cannot quite understand the meaning for anything but a point on it and a predicted value. Also, I do only know this way to compute it, so how do I compute it in the other 2 ways? Plus, the output I get gives several upper and lower values for the interval. What does that mean?

Comment: see `confint` as in `mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + am, data = mtcars); confint(mod)` and type `?confint` into the R console to learn more

Comment: And pay attention in your course material to the distinction between standard deviation and standard error (of the estimate). The first of those relates to the #2 question while the second relates to the #1 question. The last question will be answered by two quadratic curves, above and below the regression line.

Comment: in case it's not obvious, I will point out that, because this looks a lot like homework ("I am supposed to calculate ..."), the people responding are trying to give you useful suggestions for finding the answer without actually answering the question for you. StackOverflow does not have a "no homework" policy, but the R help lists (from which many of us have migrated) do -- I think that tends to spill over into the [r] culture on StackOverflow as well.

Answer (score 4):

You used `data.frame(beers = newbeers)` in your `predict` function, which means it is a **prediction interval**. Note that `newbeers` is a data frame consisting of new data rather than your original data (used to fit the linear model).

For confidence interval, just use `confint` function, which gives you (by default) a 95% CI for each regression coefficient (in this case, intercept and slope).

For a point on the regression line, please see the last two slides [here](http://www.maths.otago.ac.nz/home/resources/stat110/2012_Overheads_etc/Lecture_36_-_Regression_Confidence_Intervals_-_DT.pdf). The confidence interval for an individual point must be larger than for the regression line.

Hope this helps!